# Different parameters type for typed factory in Castle Windsor

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, typed-factory-facility

Given an interface like this:

```
public interface IFooFactory
{
  IFoo Create();
  void Release(IBar bar);
}
```

and assuming that the `IFoo` must implement `IBar`, will Castle Windsor know what to do with the object or are we creating any issues where the object types isn't exactly the same? The documentation did not say one way or other whether this is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will. The declared type on the releasing method doesn't matter to Windsor. So all following methods will have the same behaviour:

```
void Release(IBar obj)
void ReleaseMe(IFoo obj)
void Exterminate(Object obj)
```

Having different types in your create and release methods may be a bit confusing to whoever will end up using your `IFooFactory` though.

Comment: Thanks. I agree it's a bit strange to use different types. In my scenario, we will have a complex class hierarchy that involves multiple generic parameter types. Each derived class will implement the generic base using specific types and additionally have an unique interface, each which must derive from a common base nongeneric interface. That way, the caller does not need to know what generic arguments they need; only specify the derived interface to get the correct concrete implementation, and still have a generic release method.